# Navigate to a random path to run a UNIX shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, path

I want to run a script from a location - The location of the script will change as per the application name and the version but the script name and directory pattern will remain the same.
`/dev/<My-APP>/<APP-VERSION>/install-app.sh`

eg:

```
/dev/ninja-app/series1.0/install-app.sh
/dev/ninja-app/series3.2/install-app.sh
/dev/chrome/release12.3/install-app.sh
```

The app-name and version are little unpredictable so I can't give them as parameters. IS there any way to navigate to the latest install-app.sh of the ninja-app.

The files will be exploded from a tar ball, so I am thinking of finding the latest install-app.sh file and get its location  or to save the path into a variable while extracting so that it can be used at a later point

Comment: What does "latest" mean in this context? Are the version numbers in "<APP-VERSION>" the determiner here? Can you count on those being sortable in some form?

Comment: I can't count on the App-Version , at times I need to deploy the older releases.

Comment: Then how are you going to select which version you want to run?

Comment: You could pass the app version as an option in your script. Is that something that'd work for you?

Comment: Make a symlink called `current` pointing at the current release before you create the tarball, then execute `current\install-app.sh`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried few different approaches and the best one so far was to save the location of the script into a file while I extract the zip/tar file.

**unzip /apps/packages/* -d /UAT/apps/ | grep installScript.ksh | cut -d":" -f2 > /tmp/install_script**

I could grep on the install_script in any of my dependent scripts and extract the location of the script.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to work interactively, you could do something like this:

First I recreated your directory structure (kind of)

```
AirBoxOmega:~ d$ ls -R stack  
chrome      ninja-app   simple_menu.sh

stack/chrome:
release12.3

stack/chrome/release12.3:
install_app.sh

stack/ninja-app:
series1.0   series3.2

stack/ninja-app/series1.0:
install_app.sh

stack/ninja-app/series3.2:
install_app.sh
```

I also created a mock install_app.sh script in one of the directories

```
AirBoxOmega:~ d$ cat stack/chrome/release12.3/install_app.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "hello, world"
```

And then there's this very simple script that creates a menu built around the output of a find command

```
AirBoxOmega:~ d$ cat stack/simple_menu.sh

select install_app in $(find ~/stack -name install_app.sh )
do
    ${install_app}
    break
done
```

So, when I run that script, I get the following

```
AirBoxOmega:~ d$ stack/simple_menu.sh
1) /Users/d/stack/chrome/release12.3/install_app.sh
2) /Users/d/stack/ninja-app/series1.0/install_app.sh
3) /Users/d/stack/ninja-app/series3.2/install_app.sh
#? 1
hello, world
AirBoxOmega:~ d$ stack/simple_menu.sh
1) /Users/d/stack/chrome/release12.3/install_app.sh
2) /Users/d/stack/ninja-app/series1.0/install_app.sh
3) /Users/d/stack/ninja-app/series3.2/install_app.sh
#? 2
goodbye, world
AirBoxOmega:~ d$
```

and like you can see, when I choose option 1, it runs that install script and when I choose option 2 it runs another one.

If you're not able/willing to go interactive, you could probably work out some logic around just a find command.

Comment: Thanks DarrellFx - this is a small snippet invoked as a part of my deployment workflow, unfortunately it won't allow me to enter any values at runtime- It's a one click automation.   From my jenkins I will select the build and version and my script should download, extract and deploy the package.